# Update a formula in excel using Java

Tags: java, excel, formula

I'm starting to build an app (in java) and I am having some problems.I'm pretty new with all that and I'm getting a little lost.

I am trying to export some info to an excel template. I have no problem with that, but the template has some excel formulas.

When I open the template all the info is there, but in order to see the results of the formulas i have to copy/paste all the values given by the app.

I've found a sentence to update all the formulas

```
workbookInfDef.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
```

But it doesn't work. An error stop happens with it and the app collapses...

I would be really greatfull if anyone could help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f you're using XSSF workbooks, you can re-evaluate all formula cells as follows:

```
XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook)
```

A similar API exists if you're using an HSSF workbook:

```
HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook)
```

Or, depending on exactly how you're set up and what specifically you're trying to get accomplished, you should be able to find your solution here